# How do I set the selected value in a dropdown based on the selection of another dropdown using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to set the selection in a drop down to a specific selection based on what someone selects in another drop down. I am using knockout js and here is the knockout code for the select that I need to have the value updated.

```
self.availableSex = ko.observableArray([
    new selectionOption("Male", "M"),
    new selectionOption("Female", "F")
]);
self.selectedSex = ko.observable();
```

and the html protion

```
<select data-bind="options: availableSex,
     optionsText: 'name',
     value: selectedSex,
     optionsCaption: 'Select'" required>
</select>
```

I want to have it select Male or Female based on another drop down. I know how to get the values, I just can't seem to set this to what I want it to be set to based on the other drop down.

thanks for any help. I hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). Just do a search on the page(it's towards the bottom)

[EDIT]

based on comment I updated the example

What you would do is

```
self.others = ko.observableArray([1,2]);
self.selectedOther = ko.observable();

self.availableSex = ko.observableArray([
    new selectionOption("Male", "M"),
    new selectionOption("Female", "F")
]);
self.selectedSex = ko.observable();
self.selectedSex.subscribe(function(newValue){
    //newValue should be of type selectionOption
    if(newValue.value === "M"){ 
      self.selectedOther(1);
    }else{
     self.selectedOther(2);
    }
    //set other observable value
});
```

I've made an assumption here that `selectionOption` looks like something like this:

```
var selectionOption = function(name, value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};
```

hence why I do `newValue.value`

as another note I'm not 100% sure as to how knockout compares complex objects so if you had to do `self.selectedOther(some complex Object)` you may not get desired behavior. I usually do a look up, on the source, and pass in the same reference to be safe.

Comment: The callback should have a parameter, which would make sense to use here.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and just fixed it.

Comment: I am not understanding how this is going to work. I have read over the documentation, and I am not quite understanding how this is going to set the selected value of the availableSex drop down to "F" based on what I select from the relationship drop down. can you please explain how this works?

Comment: you have to do the selection yourself, this gives you a way to being notified that the value has changed, I'll update the example to help you out a bit more.